# How to prove this conjecture with Converse problem

Tags: geometry

**Problem**:Let $\Delta ABC$,such the point $D$ on $AB$,such $$AD=AC,~~~~CD=AB,~~~~\angle BAC=100^{\circ}$$ show that: $\angle ACB=50^{\circ}$

I have solve this problem,Following is my solution:
[image]

> take the $E$ such $\Delta ABE$ is equilateral,since
>   $$\angle BAC=100^{\circ},AD=AC\Longrightarrow \angle EAC=40^{\circ}=\angle ADC$$
>   so we have
>   $$\Delta ADC\cong\Delta CAE$$ so we have
>   $$AC=CE$$
>   since
>   $\Delta ABE$is equilateral,so we have
>   $AB=BE$
>   so we have
>   $$\Delta ABC\cong EBC$$
>   then we have
>   $$\angle ABC=\angle EBC=\dfrac{60^{\circ}}{2}$$
>   so the $$\angle ACB=50^{\circ}$$

I conjecture the conversen problem is also right.But How prove it

**Converse problem**:

Let $\Delta ABC$,such the point $D$ on $AB$,such $$AD=AC,~~~~CD=AB,~~~~\angle ACB=50^{\circ}$$ show that: $\angle BAC=100^{\circ}$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $\angle ABC =2x$. From the triangle $ACD$ we have

$$\sin x=\frac{DC}{2AC} \quad (1)$$

Sine rule at the triangle $ABC$:

$$\frac{AC}{\sin(50°+2x)}=\frac{AB}{\sin(50°)} \quad(2)$$

We know that $AB=DC$, so putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together we have:

$$2\cdot \sin x\cdot\sin (50°+2x)=\sin 50°$$

Now, solving the above equation by computer we can see two solutions:

$$x=50° \quad \text{and} \quad x=22,62°$$

So your guess is not true.

We have two possible values for $\angle BAC$ which are $100°$ and $45,24°$.

Answer (score 0):

$\angle ABC=\alpha$ , $0< \alpha < 50^\circ$

Let $R$ be the radius of the circumscribed circle $ABC$.

$$AB = 2R\cdot sin50^\circ$$

$AC= 2Rsin\alpha$

$\angle BAC = 130^\circ - \alpha$

$$CD = 2AC \left( sin\frac{1}{2}\angle { BAC} \right)
 = 4R\cdot sin\alpha \cdot sin\left(65^\circ - 
\frac{\alpha}{2} \right) = f(\alpha)$$

I want to show that $f(\alpha)$ is strictly increasing function.

If it is true, then the number of $\alpha$ satisfying $ AB = CD $ is at most one.

And we know that there is one existing case. Thus the converse problem is proved.

$f'(\alpha)= 
4R \cdot cos\alpha \cdot sin\left(65^\circ - 
\frac{\alpha}{2} \right) - 
2R \cdot sin\alpha \cdot cos\left(65^\circ - 
\frac{\alpha}{2} \right) $

When $\alpha$ is increasing, both $cos\alpha$ and 
$ sin\left(65^\circ - \frac{\alpha}{2} \right)$ are decreasing,

and both $sin\alpha$ and 
$ cos\left(65^\circ - \frac{\alpha}{2} \right) $ are increasing.

So $f'(\alpha)$ is decreasing function, and

$$ f'(\alpha) \ge f'(50^\circ) = 
4R \cdot cos50^\circ \cdot sin40^\circ - 
2R \cdot sin50^\circ \cdot cos40^\circ 
\approx 0.479 R > 0$$

Done.